# How to cut part of a "curl" answer

Tags: shell-script, shell, curl, cut, html

I have been having a look at this for a while but I haven't found any answer yet.

I've got a `curl` command to send a HTTP POST request to a server, then I have created a script called "tmg.sh" which looks like the next one:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "There you go:"
sleep 3s
curl "http://tmg.xunta.gal/consulta-tarxeta?blah_blah_blah&numero=$1"
echo "Thanks!"
```

Right then, so when I write the next command on the terminal:

```
chmode u+x ./tmg.sh
```

Because for some reason even in root account if I don't do this, it returns: `bash: ./tmg.sh: Permission denied`, but anyway let's go on, after I have done that, when I write the following:

```
./tmg.sh NUMBER_GOES_HERE
```

That number is the variable, then I got this answer:

```
There you go:
<html code not relevant>
<div class="infoContido"><p>Non hai ningunha recarga para o n&uacute;mero de tarxeta introducido.</p></div>
<html code not relevant>
Thanks!
```

Right, here comes my question, how can I get **just a part of the whole HTML code**? I mean, I just want a part of the website, something like this:

```
Non hai ningunha recarga para o número de tarxeta introducido.
```

Also, I'd like to notice that as I get a **full** page, there are plenty of `<p>`, `<div>`... Is that possible, if it is, how should I edit my script to get just this part?

Thank you so much and have a lovely day!

Comment: Please provide a working example, with the exact command you are running, the exact web-site address, the output, and the expected result. Please use a public website which everyone can access for the example.

Comment: This is a very simple task with an Xpath parser, but which one to use depends on your platform. Also, your terminology is off; you want to "extract" the text from an HTML "element". Google that (maybe add "div" and "class") and you should get plenty of hits. (No obvious duplicates on this site; this isn't really a Unix problem, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not explain how the text you want should be identified.

If you just want the text, try with `links` instead:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "There you go:"
sleep 3s
links -dump "http://tmg.xunta.gal/consulta-tarxeta?blah_blah_blah&numero=$1"
echo "Thanks!"
```

If the line identifier is "infoContido" this might be the solution:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "There you go:"
sleep 3s
curl "http://tmg.xunta.gal/consulta-tarxeta?blah_blah_blah&numero=$1" | grep infoContido | cut -d\> -f2 
echo "Thanks!"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class of the div object you want will always be `infoContido`, you can use [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) with a command like:

```
curl "http://tmg.xunta.gal/consulta-tarxeta?blah_blah_blah&numero=$1" | pup "div.infoContido"
```

Answer (score -2):

Send the curl output to a new file. For example in the above mentioned case.

```
curl "http://tmg.xunta.gal/consulta-tarxeta?blah_blah_blah&numero=$1" | tee -a /var/tmp/mycurl
```

Now all you need to do is grep your line from this new file.

```
cat /var/tmp/mycurl | grep Non hai ningunha recarga para o número de tarxeta introducido.
```

Comment: Until something puts a line break between any of the words, which has no effect on the HTML but completely breaks your "parser".

Comment: With your logic, a simple echo would be enough .... `echo "Non hai ningunha recarga para o número de tarxeta introducido."` OP wants to "grep" what is enclosed between `<p>` and `</p>`. Does not know what text it is inside those tags....